# Fedora 17, Dell Laptop 15 SE

Tags: fan, dell-inspiron, fedora-17

Today, I just got my Dell Laptop 15 SE, i put fedora 17, but i don't know why the FAN is always on, making lots of noise, before there was windows 8 on it, it was not making noise

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: It's better to ask specific questions rather than simply making a statement.

Comment: try  i8kutils: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=387798

Answer (score 0):

Fan speed is connected to heat, which is connected to power consumption. If the CPU and GPU wake up less, the power consumption and generated heat will be lower and the fan will run less.

I ran powertop on my laptop and in the last tab (tunables) try switching the values to "Good" (enter key). If that works, the effects will disappear after reboot. You must make a script based on those tuning and put it in /etc/rc.d/rc.local

To get the commands to run, run "powertop --html" and it will generate a HTML file telling you which commands you can run to reduce the power consumption.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was `i8kutils`

I also have a Dell Inspiron 15R SE except with Ubuntu 12.04-amd64.

I solved this problem installing [this package](https://launchpad.net/i8kutils) and as I think this is the only solution available, and the package was a little outdated, I updated the package, fixed bugs and continue to work in this in the site below.